# How to detect the release of a switch in a keyboard matrix using a microcontroller?

Tags: c, arduino, embedded, microcontroller, microchip

I want to detect the release of a switch in a matrix of keys. Consider a 4*4 keys matrix, a scan by a microcontroller can easily be done to detect a key PRESS. However, I want to detect also the releases when they occur. 
Is there a more efficient way to do so than just doing another scan on each state change interrupt for the unpressed ones?

Comment: We have no idea about your hardware or software. How can we possibly answer this?

Comment: The answer greatly depends on your microcontroller and I/O you are using. Some controllers and I/O ports allow interrupt on any change, so you would be able to efficiently detect the key up just as the key down.

Comment: @daShier Thanks. The problem is how can I know it's falling or raising edge change interrupt while the interrupt will just execute the same ISR for both?

Comment: If the Input port is capable of generating an interrupt upon any change, then I would think that reading the value of the Input port in the interrupt handler would give you its current state. But much depends upon the specifics of your hardware.

Comment: IME scanning a matrix keyboard doesn’t use edge-triggered interrupts but instead reads the states of the switches on one or more input ports - so the code can detect whether a key is pressed or released by storing its previous state and comparing the new state. There are often more complex things needed like debouncing so you don’t get false release/press when switch contacts bounce - this can sometimes be done by scanning e.g. every 10ms and requiring a press or release to have been present for two or more scans before deciding that a key press or release has definitely been detected.

Comment: You most likely want the sampling to be in a timer based interrupt, and the foreground task delivers the key state changes through whatever mechanism a uart or special bus or whatever.   This ideally allows for even sampling of the inputs while still being able to report state changes.

Comment: So there are a few things to take into consideration.  To be robust against multi key presses, you should configure one pin as an output, while the 7 others are inputs with pull-up resistors enabled.  Read both row and column inputs to detect a key press.  If someone presses #1, and then presses #2 (either on purpose or accident) without releasing #1, what are you going to do?  If #2 is released, you can detect that change by saving the previous value and scanning until change, but should you react to that?

Answer (score 1):

Matrix keyboard scanning does not require any interrupt. You should create scanning function that will be called periodically. The best way is to store each key as a bit in some variable - you have 4x4 keyboard so uint16_t will perfetly fit. XOR operator is perfect for key change detection. Also don't forget to implement some key debouncing functionality.

I'd suggest following "pseudo" code or something similar (I hope there is no bug in it):

```
#define ROW_COUNT         4
#define COL_COUNT         4
#define DEBOUNCE_TIMEOUT  10   // In milliseconds

typedef uint16_t KeyState;

// This function returns current keyboard state and
// fills upKeys with keys that were pressed and downKeys with keys that were released
// It expects that key down is logic H, up is logic L
KeyState KeyboardState(KeyState* upKeys, KeyState* downKeys)
{
  static KeyState lastState = 0;
  static KeyState lastValidState = 0;
  static Timestamp lastTimestamp = 0;
  KeyState currentState = 0;
  uint8_t x, y;

  // Set defaults
  if (upKeys)
    *upKeys = 0;
  if (downKeys)
    *downKeys = 0;

  for(y = 0; y < ROW_COUNT; y++)
  {
    // Set appropriate row pin to H
    SetRowPinH(y);
    // Just to be sure that any parasitic capacitance gets charged
    SleepMicro(10);
    for(x = 0; x < COL_COUNT; x++)
    {
      // Check key pressed
      if (IsColPinSet(x))
        currentState |= 1 << ((y * COL_COUNT) + x);
    }
    // And don't forget to set row pin back to L
    SetRowPinL(y);
  }

  // Now lets do debouncing - this is important for good functionality
  // Matrix state should not change for some time to accept result
  if (lastState == currentState)
  {
    // Check if time has passed
    if ((TimestampNowMilli() - lastTimestampMilli) >= DEBOUNCE_TIMEOUT)
    {
      // Let's detect up/down changes first - it's easy, just use XOR for change detection
      if (upKeys)
        *upKeys = currentState & (lastValidState ^ currentState);
      if (downKeys)
        *downKeys = (~currentState) & (lastValidState ^ currentState);
      lastValidState = currentState;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    // Current state differs from previous - reset timer
    lastTimestampMilli = TimestampNowMilli();
  }
  lastState = currentState;

  return lastValidState;
}

int main()
{
  KeyState upKeys;
  KeyState downKeys;
  KeyState currentKeys;
  while(1)
  {
    currentKeys = KeyboardState(&upKeys, &downKeys);
    if (upKeys & 0x0001)
      printf("Key 1 pressed\n");
    if (downKeys & 0x0001)
      printf("Key 1 released\n");
  }
}
```